# Castle Windsor registration of types different from those used in type discovery

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Let's say I have the following:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
}

public interface IMyClass<T>
{
}

public class MyClass<T, T2> : IMyClass<T2>
    where T : IMyInterface<T2>
{
}

foreach(/*var impl in classes_that_implement_IInterface<T>*/)
{
    //register IMyClass<T> as MyClass<typeof(impl), T>
}
```

e.g. If I defined

```
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface<string>
{
}
```

the following will be registered:

`IMyClass<string> as MyClass<MyImplementation, string>`

Is there a neat way to do this? I can't think how to approach this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did this.. but it seems rather... abusive?

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn(typeof(IMyInterface<>))
        .Configure(x =>
        {
            var iMyInterfaceImpl = x.Implementation;

            var iMyInterface = iMyInterfaceImpl
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyInterface<>))
                .Single();

            var iMyInterfaceGenericArg0 = iMyInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var myClassImpl = typeof(MyClass<,>).MakeGenericType(iMyInterfaceImpl, iMyInterfaceGenericArg0);
            var iMyClass = typeof(IMyClass<>).MakeGenericType(iMyInterfaceGenericArg0);

            container.Register(Component.For(iMyClass).ImplementedBy(myClassImpl));
        })
);


container.Resolve(typeof(IMyClass<string>)); // MyClass<MyImplementation, string>
```